# can i return a integer for int* return type in function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, return-value

i am making a function that allocates memory for an array and returns it and if malloc() fails then it return a int -1 to show it failed.

```
int *make_array() {

    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

    if (array == NULL)

       return -1;

    array[0] = 5;
    array[1] = 9;
    array[2] = 3;

    return array;


}
```

the return type is int* which is correct for the array BUT if it fails the -1 is returned which is not int*. is it acceptable to return -1 when return type is int* if not how could i make it correct?

Comment: Why not return `NULL`?

Comment: returning NULL pointers can be dangerous

Comment: "Returning NULL pointers can be dangerous" Only if you don't *check* for `NULL`. You must still check what the function returns, why not check for the standard `NULL` pointer rather than `(int *) -1`? Which do you think is easier to read, understand, and maintain? Not to mention that `-1` is "true" when used in a boolean context. So e.g. `if (!(arr = make_array()))` is no longer possible if you don't return `NULL`.

Comment: You cannot make returning -1 from a function that returns a pointer "correct".

Comment: Returning `-1` looks more dangerous because it (with converted to a pointer in implementation-defined manner) may be difficult to be distinguished from valid pointers.

Comment: Always return NULL on failure if the function returns a pointer.

Comment: Returning `NULL` is the one sensible "I have no pointer value to return". A `-1` is absolutely unsafe.

Comment: Can someone please tell the Linux kernel guys...?

Comment: is there any way i could maintain returning -1 instead of NULL? i prefer numerical error return types

Comment: You know, that all your checks for `NULL` will fail to detect that invalid pointer and you have to add extra checks?

Comment: Why? That just make no sense in cases like this. It's also going to confuse all your coworkers and team-members. Few of them would let it pass a code-review.

Comment: What you could do instead: `int /*note the dropped asterisk! */ make_array(int** target) { *target = malloc(...); return target ? 0 : -1; /* or if you like it CRYPTIC: return -!target; */ }`, i.e. returning an error code/result value. Still you need to check that one. Better than a pointer? Pretty much in doubt of, that's just redundant information – *unless* you want to be able to distinguish various *different* error scenarios.

Comment: @Gerhardh linux kernel developers stick to one particular implementation.

Comment: @0___________ sure. but that doesn't make it less ugly and error prone. They are not immune against using simple `NULL` checks for these kind of pointers.

Comment: @Gerhardh there is a much better and safer way. Simply add an additional parameter like in my answer. Then you will have everything you want - pointer and the status(error) code.

Comment: so as a general rule, whenever i work with pointer return types i should return NULL upon error?

Comment: Re "*Returning NULL pointers can be dangerous*", So it -1. Returning anything but a valid pointer is dangerous. That includes `NULL`, but also `-1`. But there's no escaping it.

Comment: Suppose you can return anything you want. What will you **do** with that `-1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to check the return value *in any case* anyway – but the typical way to check a pointer is:

```
int* ptr = make_array();
if(!ptr)
{
    // error handling
}
```

If you have pointers as a return value then the general expectation is that you get a null pointer in case of errors – and you break this expectation by returning `-1` converted to a pointer, thus produce a great surprise. *Anything else but safe!* Don't do that. Just *don't* do that.

*If* you want to be able to return error codes then do so *explicitly*! One possible variant might look as follows:

```
int make_array(int** target)
{
    *target = malloc(/*...*/);
    if(!*target)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

An alternative variant might return the pointer to array and accept a pointer to `int` to store an error code at: `int* make_array(int* error_code)`, see [@0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73109526/1312382).

Note, though, that in given case this information (both variants) is redundant and doesn't provide any more information than simply returning a null pointer, so I recommend rather sticking with the previous variant.

The error code style gets interesting as soon as you need to be able to distinguish various *different* error conditions, which doesn't seem to be the case here, though.

Comment: so as a general rule, whenever i work with pointer return types i should return NULL upon error?

Comment: @programme3219873 Indeed. If you consider returning `NULL` unsafe then returning anything else is even far more. If allocation failing appears an error fatal enough to do so you *might* consider `exit(-1)` instead, especially if you are *not* writing a library (in that latter case I'd leave this rather to the user so that she/he still can add some cleanup work – if you don't need such work yourself, it might be added using `atexit` function, too, then you *can* call `exit`, but that should be documented appropriately; yet another alternative is providing a callback mechanism for).

Comment: @programme3219873 *If* you decide to call `exit` from a library you *could* allow the user to provide a custom error code so that it might exit with `-1` on its own while your library would exit with whatever the user decides – while default remains `-1`...

Comment: ... or even provide a custom fatal error handler function which can do arbitrary other things then `exit` or `abort` or maybe other ways of quitting.

Comment: @aschepler Good idea – then exit might remain default if nothing else is provided...

Answer (score 0):

C standard has `intptr_t` (and `uintptr_t`) type which can accommodate any void pointer.

> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property
> that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then
> converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal
> to the original pointer

Unfortunately, it does not work in the opposite direction. Some intptr_t values might be trap representations if converted to a pointer.

In portable code you cant assume that `(intptr_t)-1` can be converted to a void pointer.

Return `NULL` if function fails.

If you want to return some additional status information simply add an additional parameter

```
int *make_array(int *status) 
{
    int *result;

    /* some code */

    if(status) //caller might not need to know the status
    {
        *status = status_code;
    }
    return result; 
}
```